Take table header text to prepend on table body cell
I have a table and need to get it responsive. What I need to do is to take each column's header's text to prepend on this column's body cell by using Jquery.
Problem: I am getting all 3 headers text prepend on all table body cells! ( It should be: CountryAlfreds, but I get CountryContactCompanyAlfreds, for example)
Please take a look at my sample below and direct me how to take each column's header's text to prepend on this column's body cell.
Any help would be appreciated!


$('thead tr th').each( function(e) {
var headerText = $(this).html();
console.log("Header " + headerText);

 $(`table tbody tr td`).prepend("<span>" + headerText + "</span>")

})
span {
color: red;
font-weight: 700
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
 
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>




It should be: CountryAlfreds that makes little sense.  Did you mean CompanyAlfreds?

You need to consider the index of TD as well


$('thead tr th').each( function(e) {

var thIndex = $(this).index();
var headerText = $(this).html();
console.log("Header " + headerText);

$(`table tbody tr`).each(function(){

    $(this).find("td").eq(thIndex).prepend("<span>" + headerText + "</span>");
});
});
span {
color: red;
font-weight: 700
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
 
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>




Thank you very much for pointing out the missing part!  It works beautifully.

I'm not sure to have understood correctly, but if this is what you're looking for, I would suggest putting each column's cells in the same class:


$('thead tr th').each( function(e) {
var headerText = $(this).html();
console.log("Header " + headerText);

 $(`table tbody .${headerText.toLowerCase()}`).prepend("<span>" + headerText + "</span>")

})
span {
color: red;
font-weight: 700
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
 
  <tr>
    <td class="company">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td class="contact">Maria Anders</td>
    <td class="country">Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="company">Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td class="contact">Francisco Chang</td>
    <td class="country">Mexico</td>
  </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>




Thank you, user27425627 very much for sharing your code, that works as expected! But in my project, I cannot touch the table because it is generated from a backend.   Your code is very useful, I have learned another way to solve the problem.  Thank you again.

$('table tbody tr td').prepend("<span>" + headerText + "</span>")

This line selected all <td> elements in the table body and prepended the header text to each of them.
As a result, every cell got the same text from all headers, leading to outputs like "CountryContactCompanyAlfreds" because the prepend operation was not contextually limited to the correct cells.
So the steps are to get the expected output

Storing Header Texts
const headers = $('table thead th').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();

Iterating Through Each Row
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {

Finding the Corresponding Header Text
$(this).find('td').each(function(index) {

Using the Correct Header Text Updating the Cell's HTML
const headerText = headers[index];
$(this).html("<span>" + headerText + "</span>" + $(this).text());




$(document).ready(function() {
    const headers = $('table thead th').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find('td').each(function(index) {
            const headerText = headers[index];
            $(this).html("<span>" + headerText + "</span>" + $(this).text());
        });
    });
});
  span {
            color: red;
            font-weight: 700;
        }
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>




Update the answer
